# Trigger mysql issue with delimiter

Tags: mysql

I get an issue when creating a trigger with MySQL.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trigversion AFTER INSERT ON offers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  update versions set value = @value + 1 limit 1;
END;//
```

Issue :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '//' at line 5

Comment: What client software are you using to connect to MySQL/input those commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per @eggyal's comments. It matters what platform you are running the SQL query from.
I dont think `DELIMITER` is valid SQL syntax, I believe its provided by PHPMyadmin.

If you are running from an environment like PHP, try the query without setting a new delimiter, e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigversion AFTER INSERT ON offers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  update versions set value = @value + 1 limit 1;
END;
```

#### Explanation

per the OP's comment that the command was being run against PHPMyadmin, I think its probably worth noting, that in that case, I think it was simply a syntax error in the query, where the delimiter wasn't being reset properly after the trigger. 
I believe this query should fix the error and run on Phpmydmin - but importantly *won't* run through PHP (PDO)

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER trigversion AFTER INSERT ON offers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  update versions set value = @value + 1 limit 1;
    END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: are you sure? did you try running the SQL?

Comment: cool, outof interest what enviroment were you running the query from?